# Compound Primary Keys - Using Update Commands. How to increment

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

EDIT: was a design issue

**my revised final ERD**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDj6i.png

I am undergoing a computing project for Alevel computing. 
The project consists of a 6 tabled Microsoft access database. I am using vb.net to code the application for a student tracking system.

My ERD is below:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/Xl0gS.png]

**My problem: How to insert a new compound Primary key into a existing table?**
If I increment StudID and CourseID in tblContact then I need to increment them in tblStudentCourse which leads to records not pointing to the right directions..

For enforcing the relationships I am using the .relations with the dataset.

```
'Student - StudentCourse
    DS.Relations.Add(New DataRelation("StudStudCorRelation", DTStudents.Columns("StudID"), DTStudentCourses.Columns("StudID"), True))
    'Course - StudentCourse
    DS.Relations.Add(New DataRelation("CourStudCorRelation", DTCourses.Columns("CourseID"), DTStudentCourses.Columns("CourseID"), True))

    StudCourseCompPK(0) = DTStudentCourses.Columns("StudID")
    StudCourseCompPK(1) = DTStudentCourses.Columns("CourseID")
    StudCourseContactCompPK(0) = DTContacts.Columns("StudID")
    StudCourseContactCompPK(1) = DTContacts.Columns("CourseID")
    StudCourseStudTMACompPK(0) = DTStudentTMAS.Columns("StudID")
    StudCourseStudTMACompPK(1) = DTStudentTMAS.Columns("CourseID")
    'Enforces the relations between these 2 keys
    DS.Relations.Add(New DataRelation("CPKContact", StudCourseCompPK, StudCourseContactCompPK, True))
    DS.Relations.Add(New DataRelation("CPKStudentTMA", StudCourseCompPK, StudCourseStudTMACompPK, True))
    DS.EnforceConstraints = True

    DTStudentCourses.PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() {DTStudentCourses.Columns("StudID"), DTStudentCourses.Columns("CourseID")}
```

But the last line here:

```
    DTStudentCourses.PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() {DTStudentCourses.Columns("StudID"), DTStudentCourses.Columns("CourseID")}
```

Needs to be used to retrieve the keys from tblStudentCourse which I am unsure about what todo

If anybody could take a look at this problem I would be very grateful.

Harry

**Revised ERD**

[image]

Comment: I reckon you would have a much better chance of a reply if you add a homework tag and reduce the problem to adding the compound key, a *little* code to show willing, and some table schemas.

Comment: Why have you got CourseID in tblContact? If the contact is only relevant to a student-course combination, surely the student-course must be created before a contact is relevant? If the contact is only relevant to a student, the course id is not required. It might be worth considering an autonumber id on the student-course table. I think your problems may be due to design issues, so it may be worth posting a question on the design.

Comment: `Why have you got CourseID in tblContact?` Because I thought I needed to enforce the one-to-many relationship between tblStudentCourse and tblContact, unless I need to use another foreign key?

Comment: Is the relationship on contacts between studentcourses and contacts or between students and contacts? What is a contact? A letter? Do you need the link to courses or is a refernce without a link sufficient, given that you can get the course information another way?

Comment: Ah, you are right Remou, the relationship is between a Student and nothing but the student. A contact is when the tutor(user) emails or telephones a student (i.e. makes contact) so the relationship doesn't need a course to be relevant. My revised [ERD](http://i.imgur.com/cf3td.png)

Comment: Okay. Now look at assignments. How does the relationship work there? Are there a set number of assignments per course? Do you need another intermediate table StudentCourseAssignment? If the assigmnet is studentcourse, consider adding an autonumber key to the studentcourse intermediate table which can be used in the assigments table.

Comment: For each Course there are a different amount of TMA(Tutor marked assignment) thus a one-to-many relationship. Each of these TMAs can have multiple students and each grade can have multiple TMAS thus the circle of doom appears. Edit: in tblStudentCourse there is a grade for a particular TMA which reflects a particular student on a particular course. Thus the 3 linking tables reflect the above diagram.

Comment: Okay, each Student is on a a course, where each student have multiple TMAs relating to them based on the course they are undertaking and each TMA has a grade that the student received. So I am going to implement my revised ERD and hope this will work.

Comment: Sorry to go on. But I had a sudden thought: Does CourseID in tblStudentTMA need to exist? Because in tblStudentTMA the grade corresponds to a TMA which is on a course which then relates to a student, so you dont need the relationship between studentcourse and studentTMA directly?

Comment: It may be useful to have, but it is only necessary to have a relationship if you need it as a constraint. The TMA relates to a course, so the TMAID is probably your constraint, not the CourseID.

Comment: If you have not already done so, you may wish to read http://www.r937.com/relational.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I increment StudID and CourseID in tblContact then I need to
>   increment them in tblStudentCourse which leads to records not pointing
>   to the right directions.

No, values increment in only one table. Anywhere else you use those incremented values, you essentially copy them.

So tblStudent.StudID might be an integer that gets incremented by one for each new student. tblCourse.CourseID might be an integer that gets incremented by one for each course. To store data in tblStudentCourse, you copy one appropriate, existing integer from tblStudent.StudID and another appropriate, existing integer from tblCourse.CourseID.

StudID is incremented in only one place--tblStudent. CourseID is incremented in only one place--tblCourse.

Comment: So when creating a new contact record the values StudID and CourseID in tblContact will be the same as in tblStudent, tblCourse? Because I still need to enforce a many to many relationship between tblStudentCourse and tblContact, because students can have many contact times.

Comment: @Apple: If I understand your design correctly, when you create a new contact row, the values for StudID and CourseID will match one row in tblStudentCourse. That guarantees the contact is about a course the student is actually in.  ("Students can have many contact times" describes a one-to-many relationship.)

Comment: That is correct, but(this is where my knowledge falls apart) using compound primary keys the values in tblstudentCourse surely must be another set of new keys? Ex. when dealing without CPKs you would have a e.g. ContactID which would be in tblContact and tblStudentCourse (note ignore the convo with Remou atm). So the new values relating to tblContact must be in another magic storage location, i.e. merging the 2 foreign keys to create a compound primary key. What I don't know is where is this location...

Comment: Let's say that Catcall has StudID = 32. I'm taking only one course; it has CourseID = 7. Then "my" row in tblStudentCourse would have StudID = 32 and CourseID = 7.

Comment: .. and then would (using the original ERD) StudID and CourseID in tblContact have 32 and 7? thus would their be a point in having that table at all?

Comment: @Apple: Yes, "my" row in tblContact would also have StudID = 32 and CourseID = 7. The point in having a table of contacts *like you have in the graphic* would be to store information about contacts between a specific student and some unidentified person (a teacher?) with respect to a specific course.